Segmentation Fault of Apache SSL Engine
for quite some time now I've had an issue with my server, where apache would run into a segmentation fault every once in a while. The server runs Ubuntu 22 and a regular package based installation of Nextcloud. Besides that there's nothing really running on the server. You can find the current versions of the respective applications below:
Nextcloud version (eg, 29.0.5): 29.0.7
Operating system and version (eg, Ubuntu 24.04): Ubuntu 22.04.5
Apache or nginx version (eg, Apache 2.4.25): Apache 2.4.52
PHP version (eg, 8.3): 8.1.2
The server runs well until at some point it runs into a segmentation fault which prevents users from logging into the Nextcloud and also the Nextcloud calendar/contacts sync on a mobile phone wouldn't work anymore. When logging in, the response is “Temporary error. Please try again.” and the console in the browser shows “Request failed with status code 500 (ERR_BAD_RESPONSE)”.
If a user was logged in before, the user also cannot reach the nextcloud instance. The user just gets an error message in the browser.
The log shows repetitive segmentation faults, always happening when someone tries to access the nextcloud instance and somehow related to ssl_engine and request.c. I tried searching for this online but couldn’t find anyone with similar issues.
The error is usually gone once I restart apache. It reappears irregularly, sometimes after a day, sometimes after 5 days. Initially I thought it was the memory for php that was not enough and I kept increasing it but I’m not sure about that. It does seem like some login cache is overflowing at some point and then the segmentation fault occurs but I don’t know enough about this to know where the issue is. I would highly appreciate any help here!
The output of my Apache log:
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.214448 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.214466 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.288931 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289006 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289022 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289038 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289094 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289336 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read finished
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289357 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2209): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289385 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2254): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.3, Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289615 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(508): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0xda -> subcache 26)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289674 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(745): AH00842: expiring 2 and reclaiming 0 removed socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289688 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(765): AH00843: we now have 2 socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289702 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(862): AH00847: insert happened at idx=38, data=(7992:8024)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289714 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(865): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=36/3, data_pos/data_used=7568/635
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289763 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(530): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289781 2024] [ssl:trace2] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2061): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=da5851a6dbf4651fc8444161ee00ca93faefb9403118171cdba95d5334e7618c timeout=300s (session caching)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.289939 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290039 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(508): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0x69 -> subcache 9)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290091 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(745): AH00842: expiring 1 and reclaiming 0 removed socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290104 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(765): AH00843: we now have 6 socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290116 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(862): AH00847: insert happened at idx=54, data=(11305:11337)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290128 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(865): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=48/7, data_pos/data_used=10035/1481
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290141 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_socache_shmcb.c(530): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290154 2024] [ssl:trace2] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2061): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=69a7f47aace4a38903269c136695169bf8c8d5f77bfbb22d32ba54509d9971c9 timeout=300s (session caching)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290214 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.290314 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.357064 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.357141 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.357419 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 1366212] ssl_engine_kernel.c(415): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 4 (server myserver.de:443)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.357700 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.357719 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.357733 2024] [core:trace3] [pid 1366212] request.c(360): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /remote.php/dav/files/
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.358258 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.358277 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366212] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.358290 2024] [core:trace3] [pid 1366212] request.c(360): [client 138.246.3.186:40804] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /dav/files/
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.493826 2024] [core:notice] [pid 951769] AH00051: child pid 1366209 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.495696 2024] [watchdog:debug] [pid 1366243] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.496043 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 1366243] proxy_util.c(2122): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.496099 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 1366243] proxy_util.c(2182): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.496190 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 1366243] proxy_util.c(2230): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1366243 for (*)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.498632 2024] [watchdog:debug] [pid 1366244] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.498939 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 1366244] proxy_util.c(2122): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.498960 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 1366244] proxy_util.c(2182): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:53.499034 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 1366244] proxy_util.c(2230): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1366244 for (*)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.047097 2024] [ssl:info] [pid 1366213] [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH01964: Connection to child 7 established (server myserver.de:443)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.047661 2024] [ssl:trace2] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_rand.c(125): Server: Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048152 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2205): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048312 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: before SSL initialization
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048332 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048400 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048417 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048436 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048454 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: before SSL initialization
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.048515 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2395): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername myserver.de found
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.049093 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.050929 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.051247 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.051292 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.051395 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.059586 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.060072 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write finished
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.060094 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.060113 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133275 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133391 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133407 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133425 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133479 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133706 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read finished
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133726 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2209): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133753 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2254): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.3, Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133951 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(508): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0xa1 -> subcache 1)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133985 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(745): AH00842: expiring 1 and reclaiming 0 removed socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.133999 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(765): AH00843: we now have 1 socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134013 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(862): AH00847: insert happened at idx=50, data=(10475:10507)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134025 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(865): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=49/2, data_pos/data_used=10263/424
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134039 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(530): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134056 2024] [ssl:trace2] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2061): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=a165b4ef9550baa858ffbf269a9d33b41e14faa1302727a41f03e13521380763 timeout=300s (session caching)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134256 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134358 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(508): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0x6c -> subcache 12)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134398 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(745): AH00842: expiring 1 and reclaiming 0 removed socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134411 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(765): AH00843: we now have 0 socache entries
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134424 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(862): AH00847: insert happened at idx=59, data=(12377:12409)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134437 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(865): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=59/1, data_pos/data_used=12377/212
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134449 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_socache_shmcb.c(530): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134463 2024] [ssl:trace2] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2061): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=6cb11e0c00ca6278a3286e6cbe6dae92766e6c6d245c98ac89129d54a19d177a timeout=300s (session caching)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134524 2024] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2213): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.134623 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.200649 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.200794 2024] [ssl:trace1] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_io.c(584): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] BUG: bio_filter_in_ctrl() should not be called with cmd=76
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.201072 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 1366213] ssl_engine_kernel.c(415): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 7 (server myserver.de:443)
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.202708 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.202751 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.202765 2024] [core:trace3] [pid 1366213] request.c(360): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /remote.php/dav/files/
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.203348 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.203369 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1366213] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.203382 2024] [core:trace3] [pid 1366213] request.c(360): [client 138.246.3.186:40810] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /dav/files/
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:54.495198 2024] [core:notice] [pid 951769] AH00051: child pid 1366212 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Nov 04 09:11:55.495853 2024] [core:notice] [pid 951769] AH00051: child pid 1366213 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2


Thanks a lot in advance!

A segmentation fault is not caused by a lack of memory. It always is an internal bug in the implementation of the crashing component. It is the exception that is raised if an internal object pointer points to a segment in the memory that is NOT reserved for the process trying to access it. Typically that means it is an old pointer pointing to an object that has been deallocated since. The operating system records such access attempts and blocks the requests, crashing the process by that. This is to prevent arbitrary processes from accessing memory segments that belong to other processes.

It probably makes sense to search in the bug tracking system of the http server for existing issues. And to open a new one if you cannot find anything related.

Thanks for the help.
While I agree with most of your comment @arkascha, a segmentation fault can indeed be caused by a stack overflow, i.e. requiring more space than allocated or available. That's what my initial thought was.
Nevertheless, I will create an issue and hope that it is dealt with. Thanks again.

OK, if you say so ... I have never heard that a segmentation fault is caused when allocating memory. Typically a memory allocation exception is raised in such case. Simply because the process did not yet try to access that memory segment, but only to allocate it. But sure, some specific operating system might behave different in that ...
